# How to select previous or next row ordered by multiple text columns

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I have a form to edit mysql table columns. There are links that I can click onto and load Previous, Next, First or Last row. I can order the columns (max. four columns to be ordered). So when I press Prev. or Next, the columns have to be ordered first and then I can get the result. I use mysql View for this. It is important to know that columns are text, but id is number. I usually order by first text columns and then by id.

And here is my query that worked to me for single column order.

Previous:

```
  SELECT  x.* 
    FROM  test_view x, test_view y 
   WHERE   y.`id` = 13 
           AND ( x.`cat` < y.`cat` OR ( x.`cat` = y.`cat` AND x.`id` < y.`id`)) 
ORDER BY  x.`cat`, x.`id` DESC   
   LIMIT  0,1
```

Next:

```
  SELECT  x.* 
    FROM  test_view x, test_view y 
   WHERE  y.`id` = 13 
          AND (x.`cat` > y.`cat` OR (x.`cat` = y.`cat` AND x.`id` > y.`id`)) 
ORDER BY  x.`cat`, x.`id` ASC   
   LIMIT  0,1
```

I tried to expand this to find multiple columns as this:

```
SELECT x . *
FROM ukazka_view x, ukazka_view y
WHERE y.`id` =1
AND (
x.`cat` < y.`cat`
OR (
x.`cat` = y.`cat`
AND x.`id` < y.`id`
)
)
AND (
x.`typ` < y.`typ`
OR (
x.`typ` = y.`typ`
AND x.`id` < y.`id`
)
)
AND (
x.`diff` < y.`diff`
OR (
x.`diff` = y.`diff`
AND x.`id` < y.`id`
)
)
ORDER BY x.`cat` DESC , x.`typ` DESC , x.`diff` DESC , x.`id` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 1
```

But this has no results.

**Edited:**

I tried to write a query for case that actual row id is 1.

```
    SELECT x.* FROM  ukazka_view x INNER JOIN ukazka_view y ON  
( x.`cat` < y.`cat` OR 
( x.`cat` = y.`cat` AND x.`id` < y.`id`) OR
( x.`cat` = y.`cat` AND y.`id` = 1 AND x.`id` > y.`id`))
```

AND 
    ( x.`typ` < y.`typ` OR 
    ( x.`typ` = y.`typ` AND x.`id` < y.`id`) OR
    ( x.`typ` = y.`typ` AND y.`id` = 1 AND x.`id` > y.`id`))
 AND 
    ( x.`diff` < y.`diff` OR 
    ( x.`diff` = y.`diff` AND x.`id` < y.`id`) OR
    ( x.`diff` = y.`diff` AND y.`id` = 1 AND x.`id` > y.`id`))
 WHERE y.`id` = 1
 ORDER BY  x.`cat` DESC, x.`typ` DESC, x.`diff` DESC, x.`id` DESC  LIMIT 0,1

This looks for previous row. Behavior is a little bit strange but works. So when I go to last value, I got id=1. Then When I press Previous (this query) it gets to id=82, when I press again Previous id=81 and so on till I got id=2. I cannot get to id=1 only when I press/select Last.

Comment: Implicit joins are an anti-pattern. I suggest you use explicit joins instead and get out of 1989.

Comment: The first two codes was given to me by somebody who understands sql much more better then me. I am just novice, so I don't understand your comment. Also the first two codes are taken from an example from one site with very good reputation in my country.

Comment: The problem with implicit joins is that they mix filter and join criteria. This is bad and confusing and for this reason explicit join syntax, see the answer below. was invented in 1992(!). Here the join criteria are listed separately. Which makes the query much cleaner and easier to debug. Otherwise it works the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM ukazka_view x
INNER JOIN ukazka_view y 
  ON  (x.cat  < y.cat  OR (x.cat  = y.cat  AND x.id < y.id)) 
  AND (x.typ  < y.typ  OR (x.typ  = y.typ  AND x.id < y.id))  
  AND (x.diff < y.diff OR (x.diff = y.diff AND x.id < y.id))
WHERE y.id = 1
ORDER BY x.cat DESC , x.typ DESC , x.diff DESC , x.id DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

The problem I see with this query is that an id cannot be smaller than 1.
So `x.id < y.id` will always be false.
This leaves only

```
....
  ON  (x.cat  < y.cat)
  AND (x.typ  < y.typ)
  AND (x.diff < y.diff)
```

As a join criterion.

Comment: `(x.cat  < y.cat  OR (x.cat  = y.cat  AND x.id < y.id))` can be written in MySQL more compactly as: **`(x.cat, x.id) < (y.cat, y.id)`**

Comment: @ypercube, wow where did you get that gem from? I would love to have a link documenting this behavior.

Comment: @Johan: "The problem I see with this query is that an id cannot be smaller than 1." - Do you mean that the two first codes in question post should not work? I tested now your code and it seems to be working well. In this moment I am trying to repair my code to work with First and Last yet. Thanx for this code.

Comment: @Joe, The `x.id < y.id` will never work in combination with a `where y.id = 1` If y.id can be > 1, than it might work.

Comment: @Johan: I don't rememebr a link, if I find one, I'll write it here. I found it last here when trying to solve a (lexicographic) question here, ending with some quite complex code only to find out the simple `(a,b,c) < (x,y,z)` instead of my 6 line segments :)

Comment: I know that where y.id = 1 cannot work. This was just unlucky example from my actual navigation state. I've made a query to to find last record SELECT x.* FROM  ukazka_view x INNER JOIN 
  ukazka_view y ON  x.`id` > -1   
  ORDER BY  x.`cat` DESC, x.`typ` DESC, x.`diff` DESC, x.`id` DESC  LIMIT 0,1  but doesnot work. If I call this from my AJAX navigation, then even the code from Johan stops working... strange to me

Comment: @Johan, "The x.id < y.id will never work in combination with a where y.id = 1" - my last comment was confusing, I was confused. So is any way how to solve this problem, to redo the query to accept "where y.id = 1"? Many thanks